# Закрыть модальное окно и отправить POST запрос

Tags: всплывающее-окно, ajax, javascript

Есть код

http://jsfiddle.net/arashvg/xyec7psp/

При загрузке страницы открывается модальное окно с двумя кнопками. Вопрос, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ту или иную кнопку, данные из формы отправлялись, окно закрывалось, но страница не перезагружалась, то есть без обновления страницы?

---

Отправку запроса сделал так:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function send()
{
//Получаем параметры
var data = $('#mydata').val()
  // Отсылаем паметры
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SendData.php",
                data: "data="+data,
                // Выводим то что вернул PHP
                success: function(html) {
 //предварительно очищаем нужный элемент страницы
                        $("#result").empty();
//и выводим ответ php скрипта
                        $("#result").append(html);
                }
        });

}
  </script>

 <a href="#dialog" name="modal">Link</a>
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="dialog" class="window">
    <font size="6px">Hello World</font><br>     
        <form action="verification.php" method="POST" >
            <input type="hidden" name="ok" value="ok">
            <input type="button" onclick="send();" name="ok" value="ok" class="ok">
        </form>

        <form action="verification.php" method="POST" >
            <input type="hidden" name="exit" value="exit">
            <input type="button" onclick="send();" name="exit" value="exit" class="exit">
        </form>

     </div>
    <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Теперь вопрос такой: **как закрыть модальное окно?**

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$('a[name=modal]').click(function(){

    //действие закрытия окна

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST,' // метод
        url: "path", // путь, куда отправлять данные
        data: {param: 'value'} // данные в формате {параметр:'значение'}, на сервере парсятся $_POST['параметр'] равен 'значение'
    }).success(function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "done" );
    });
});
```

Comment: @A1essandro, дополнил вопрос....

Comment: @arashvg, в документации по плагину, который Вы использовали, нужно найти метод, который закрывает модальное окно, например что-то такое `$('#close-id').close()`, передать идентификатор окна в функцию `onclick="send('#dialog');"` и использовать в своей функции `$(id).close();` - где id - это аргумент функции.